# Can I place a second water token on a canteen to use its action again in the same season?

Tags: parks

[The rules](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1898/8501/files/Rules-NEWLOGO-Small.pdf?v=12672166157712510236) state:

> Once a Canteen is filled, the [water token] remains on it until the end of
> the Season and cannot be used any other way.

I believe this means *the water token cannot be used any other way*, not *the canteen cannot be used in any other way*. Partly because grammatically "cannot be used any other way" should refer to the water token, but mainly because canteens can't be used in another way and water tokens can.

I didn't see anything in the rules that would specifically prohibit placing multiple water tokens on a canteen.

The End of a Season rules do say "Empty all [canteens] by returning their [water token] to the supply". This could imply the canteens need to be emptied to be used again, otherwise why empty the canteens? However, emptying the canteens does return the water tokens to the supply, which is limited, so that could be the reason.

My gut feeling is the intent was to only be able to use a canteen once per season, but I don't think this is clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: image from the rules]

This image shows the water token being placed on the empty space on the card. If that space if filled it would mean another token couldn’t be placed there. The end of season rules refer to that ‘empty’ icon having water returned to the supply.

The use of the word ‘filled’ implies its once per season. If something is filled you can't keep adding more to it as there is not the space.